# Jsoup : How to escape from this simple img selection nightmare?

Tags: android, jsoup

I am using jsoup lib.
So I want to take img from this website
[here](http://www.non14.net/70764/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AD-%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A9-%D9%84%D8%A5%D9%81%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%8A-%D9%88%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%86)

so I used select element and my code was like that

```
Elements news2 = document.select("div.contentcolumn");
// Elements title2 = news2.select("div.catitems");
Log.d("MainActivity", "This is news = " + title);

for (Element el : news2) {
     news_object = new item();
     news_object.setTitle(el.select("h1").text());
     news_object.setauther(el.select("a").attr("abs:href"));
     news_object.setimg(el.select("ImageArea").attr("abs:src"));

     Log.d("newsdetail", "humam" + news_object.getimg());
```

and here is the source code of web site

```
<div id="ImageArea">
     <a href="/filestorage/contentfiles/2016/04_16/090416102307_140_1.jpg" 
        target="_blank">
        <img src="/filestorage/contentfiles/2016/04_16/090416102307_140_1.jpg"
             alt="المالكي: الإصلاح محاولة لإفشال المشروع الإسلامي وضرب المتدينين" 
             style="max-width:620px;">        
     </a>
</div>
```

I want to select img and put it in view img and select the text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this code line: `el.select("ImageArea").attr("abs:src")`.
Let's see what happen:

```
el.select("ImageArea") // Here we select an element with tag name ImageArea
.attr("abs:src")
```

`ImageArea` is the id of a div containing an anchor containing a targeted image.

Try this instead:

```
news_object.setimg(el.select("#ImageArea img").attr("abs:src"));
```

If the `ImageArea` element may not have an img, use the code below:

```
Element img = el.select("#ImageArea img").first();
if ( img != null ) {
    news_object.setimg(img.attr("abs:src"));
} else {
    // ...
}
```